# How do I store the Input of a Textfield and display it in another View in Swift UI?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am just learning to code and I have a question. How do I store the Input data of a Textfield and display it in another View? I tried it with Binding but it doesn't work that way. I appreciate your help

```
import SwiftUI

struct SelectUserName: View {
    
    @Binding var name: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Name", text: self.$name)
    }
}


struct DisplayUserName: View {
    
    @State private var name = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        // the name should be diplayed here!
        Text(name)
    }
}

struct DisplayUserName_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DisplayUserName()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

State should always be stored in a parent and passed down to the children. Right now, you're not showing the connection between the two views (neither reference the other), so it's a little unclear how they relate, but there are basically two scenarios:

Your current code would work if `DisplayUserName` was the parent of `SelectUserName`:

```
struct DisplayUserName: View {
    
    @State private var name = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
        SelectUserName(name: $name)
    }
}

struct SelectUserName: View {
    
    @Binding var name: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Name", text: self.$name)
    }
}
```

Or, if they are sibling views, the state should be stored by a common parent:

```
struct ContentView  : View {
    @State private var name = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        SelectUserName(name: $name)
        DisplayUserName(name: name)
    }
}

struct SelectUserName: View {
    
    @Binding var name: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Name", text: self.$name)
    }
}


struct DisplayUserName: View {
    
    var name : String //<-- Note that @State isn't needed here because nothing in this view modifies the value
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Is there a way to only store and display the Input the User types into the textfield without displaying the whole child view? For example you have a social media app and in the registration process you type in your name / gender / date of Birth .... These information should be displayed in your profile later on. I hope you can understand what I am trying to do. Sorry for the inaccurate example.

Comment: "Is there a way to only store and display the Input the User types into the textfield without displaying the whole child view?" -- I'm not really sure what this means. If you want less information, just don't include it in the View. SwiftUI is compositional, so it's easy to break everything into small child views and only use what you need. Is there something else I can clarify to make my answer workable for you?